# Is the amount of zero valued minors of a size n discrete Fourier transform matrix dependent on the amount of divisors of n?

Tags: fourier-transform

This is a [repost from Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4498591/is-the-amount-of-zero-valued-minors-of-a-size-n-discrete-fourier-transform-matri) due to lack of answers.

A [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) is a determinant of a square matrix formed from a bigger square matrix by removing rows and columns. A minor having value zero means that its associated submatrix is non invertible.

The amount of zero valued minors of a size n discrete Fourier transform matrix seems to depend on the amount of divisors of n where more zero valued minors are found with more divisors.

See [an example in radio communication](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/73055/is-fft-sub-matrix-degeneracy-a-problem-in-ofdma-for-some-type-of-noise).

How can it be shown?

How can the amount of zero valued minors be determined?